# Reverse string sentence with for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

last week Friday I had the challenge of creating a function which that capitalized all of the even words within a sentence, and reversed each odd word within a sentence. I was wondering, how would I go about using the same for loop I created to simply reverse the entire sentence itself, without capitalizing anything.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
def the_sentence(words):
sentence = words
new_sent = sentence.split(" ")
for x in range(len(new_sent)):
    if x % 2 == 0 :
        new_sent[x] = new_sent[x].upper()

    else:
        new_sent[x]=new_sent[x][::-1]
print(new_sent)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you mean `words[::-1]`?

Comment: Is this homework?  If not, why not use `words[::-1]`?

Comment: Yes, this is an optional assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `name.swapcase().` Lookup the string methods in the python 
doc....

To reverse the whole sentence just use `sentence[::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

What about `' '.join(new_sent[::-1])`?

`new_sent[::-1]` reverse the word order, `["Hello", "World"]` becomes `["World", "Hello"]`. 
And `' '.join()` would concatenate a list to a string. [Read more here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

**Edit**

`' '.join([word[::-1] for word in new_sent[::-1]])`

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been clearer. I want the words themselves to reverse, not just the order.

Example:
Input :  “This is a sentence”

Output “ecnetnes a si sihT”

Comment: @HiroshimaBubbleGum Edited my answer